# typescript iterate over typed object keys

Tags: performance, typescript, associative-array

I'm currently researching a fast way to iterate over an javascript object and found the jsperf benchmark http://jsperf.com/object-keys-iteration/46 which shows an amazing performance boost if you're using an array with strings as keys and the build in `forEach` function.

Usually I'm declaring my objects as interfaces in the following manner:

```
interface FooInterface { [key:string]:AnotherInterface; }
var foo:FooInterface = {};
```

But if I try to add the interface to an array typescript throws an error:

```
var foo:FooInterface = [];
foo['key'] = anotherInterfaceImplementation;

Cannot convert 'any[]' to 'FooInterface'
```

Is there any chance to update the interface and get the performance boost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a type assertion:

```
interface FooInterface { [key:string]:AnotherInterface; }

var foo:FooInterface = <any>[]; // ASSERT to tell the compiler that you know better
foo['key'] = anotherInterfaceImplementation;
```

Comment: Hm, that would work but it feels kind of odd to work against the compiler and add another declaration...

Comment: If you use array with number as index, and put for example just one item with index 1000, the array size would become 1001 (tested in Chrome). Use object for associative array.